# Streamlit App compiled using pyinstaller saved in network folder

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, streamlit

I created a streamlit app using pyinstaller -onedir.
It is working on my machine which have python installed.
When i share it to a computer without python, error below occurs.

[image: Error]

```
    File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "asyncio\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
NameError: name 'base_events' is not defined
[5668] Failed to execute script 'run_main' due to unhandled exception!
```

I tried pip install asyncio then compile again. it didn't work.
also tried to put the asyncio folder in root also didn't work.

Comment: does it work if you install Python on the machine?

Comment: Yes it works. The file is saved in network folder

Comment: As it turns out, the error is because the other computer trying to run the file directly in the network folder. If he copies it to his local drive and run it from there, it works fine

Comment: that seems like a practical Answer and perhaps specific to the filesystem f you'd like to Answer your own Question!

Comment: Just wondering, does sys._meipass causes that behavior?